# Select multiple fields with LINQ by multiple result by last query

Tags: linq-to-sql

I need to query a table with linq and bind the rows returned from the linq query to an object

```
WebChatDBDataContext dataContext = new WebChatDBDataContext();
var executiveSession= dataContext.ExecutiveSessions.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SessionId == httpcontext.Session.SessionID);
var talkerId = (from cRoom in dataContext.ChatRooms
                where cRoom.ExecutiveId == executiveSession.ExecutiveSessionId
                select cRoom.TalkerId
               );
var msglst = from msgPool in dataContext.MessagePools
             // I want to use talkerId from the previous query
             where msgPool.TalkerId == ???
            select msglst;
```

thanx

Comment: You're using a *query* so your `talkerId` variable is actually a *sequence* of IDs. Are you expecting it to only have a single value?

Comment: no I am not expecting it to only have a single value... I want all message in MessagePools tables which has talkerId IN(1,2,3,...etc)

Comment: Then you need to put that in the code...

Comment: Gah - misread the comment. Editing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a join. If you don't need `talkerId` for anything else, it's going to be simplest to do this in a single query:

```
var executiveSessionId = dataContext.ExecutiveSessions
        .FirstOrDefault(s => s.SessionId == httpcontext.Session.SessionID)
        .ExecutiveSessionId;

var pools = from room in dataContext.Rooms
            where room.ExecutiveId == executiveSessionId
            join pool in dataContext.MessagePools
              on room.TalkerId equals pool.TalkerId
            select pool;
```

Comment: @user1521447: I misread your original comment. Have a look now.

Comment: yes that is exactly i want. thanx for giving for valuable time